# Google maps issue when zooming (Firefox and IE)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google maps. Zooming is not smooth in FF and IE (in Chrome works well)

Could you please check this google demo (Problem is also reproducible here.):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

Is there any way to make it smooth?

UPDATE:

I have found a solution. I set my app to use v=3.4 version of google map api. Zooming is smooth now.

Comment: that's a specific problem of the browser, you cannot changed this, because that's how the browser render each image there are sending from google

Comment: but if you go to maps.google.com ... or some other google maps page it zooms nicely in FF and IE. What is specific about this very example map? :S

Comment: Can you update this again, setting it to 3.4 does not work for Firefox.